# empty function in php not working right

Tags: php

Hello for some reason I can't get my program to see if my file is empty or not if something is selected it should not go through but it is.  Here is the code

```
if (empty($_FILES['file'] ) )
    {
        echo "testing";
        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();

    }
```

Comment: include `var_dump($_FILES)` or `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: For you to see or in my program?

Comment: what exactly isn't working? try using "var_dump($_FILES);" & "echo $_FILES['file'];" to make sure that it's what you expect.

Comment: i would not check the whole array, but the file name

Comment: Okay my issue is I have a form which works everything is ok but if you do not select a file it should not go through but it does go through and its as though the file is not empty which the above code is what i use to check it.

Comment: For us to see, so we can see the data and what is happening.

Comment: @DavidBiga - what about the output of var_dump($_FILES) & echo $_FILES['file'];

Comment: array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } } Array

Comment: @DavidBiga - it seems that $_FILES['file'] isn't actually empty - it's an array :D try var_dump($_FILES['file']);

Comment: wait, are you having a problem with $_FILE['names'] that are supposedly empty being labeled as not empty, or $_FILE['names'] that are supposedly not-empty being sent as empty?

Comment: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Book1.csv" ["type"]=> string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel" ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpDC3D.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(184) }

Comment: All I need to do is check if the file add in form is empty and if it is then it will return back if it is not it will go ahead and upload into server

Comment: yeah, but what's _not_ working? what are you having a problem with? is it echoing "testing" or not with that $_FILE array?

Comment: so matter what with using empty to see if file does not contain anything it will go through so thats my issue.

Comment: it will not echo testing

Comment: it should echo that if i did not select a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language construct `empty()` and arrays in PHP do not mix well. In addition, if you have a `<input type='file' name='file' />` in your form, you *will* get a `$_FILES[]` array. You should be doing `if( !array_key_exists('file', $_FILES) ) { // no file uploaded }` to start with.

In fact, you should be doing several checks:

- If the `file` element is populated in `$_FILES`
- If there is no error (that is, `$_FILES['file']['error']` == 0)
- If there is a filename for the uploaded file's temporary location
- If PHP believes it is an uploaded file and/or it can move it

Only of *all* of those are true will you have a file to process. Otherwise you don't.

I've found following these steps religiously on a file upload handler to be thoroughly reliable.

Comment: Only when I do not select a file.

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['error']` will be 0 if there is a file uploaded. If it is *not* 0 at that step (or it doesn't exist in the array), you do not have a file.

Answer (score 2):

What do you get if you output the files array? (i.e. `print_r($_FILES);`)

Your code won't tell you if the contents of the file called `file` is empty, it will tell you if the value of `$_FILES['file']` is empty, which might not be what you want. You also might not want the logic of `empty` - have you tried this to see if there is a difference?

```
if (array_key_exists('file', $_FILES)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: if works but even if I don't enter a file it still goes through.

Answer (score 2):

From the var_dump($_FILES) you provided in the comments, it looks like it isn't echoing "testing" (i.e. it's not working) because $_FILE['file'] isn't empty.

from what you provided me:

$_FILES['file'] = array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) }

I'm not completely sure how empty() handles arrays (the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) just says it will return true for an empty array), but at the very least you'd need to either get rid of $_FILES['file']['error'] (which isn't empty since it's an int(4)), or use empty() to check something like $_FILES['file']['name']

so, using my suggestion, here's how the code would look:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo "testing";
    $seterror = 1;
    returnBack();    
}
```

or (since there might be something wrong with my understanding of PHP arrays), try this:

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo "testing";
    $seterror = 1;
    returnBack();
}
```

Comment: The problem is with using this It always see that the file is not empty and i have so clue why

Comment: @DavidBiga - sorry, I made an error in my code (which I just fixed), try with it now :)

Comment: o.o that should work...could you do var_dump($_FILES['file']['name']); ?

Comment: just fixed it :) thanks for the help but I needed to use error instead of name

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for empty files here is the code

```
$file = 'test.txt';

if(filesize($file) == NULL) {
    echo "empty"; 
}
```

Comment: worked except even if it does have a file it still goes through

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    // not uploaded
}
else
{
    // uploded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I had to do was check to see if it error - so if it did it would not go through because it would mean its empty

code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['error'] ) )
    {

        echo "file";
        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();

    }
```

Thank you so much for the help guys!

Comment: You should be checking that `$_FILES['file']['error']` is or is not 0. The construct `empty()` just happens to work because a value of 0 is interpreted as "empty" by PHP.